# Steps to Install Git from source, install Post-Git from source, and then load up Posh in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, posh-git

The Pro Git [Installing Git article](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source) says:

> If you can, it's generally useful to install Git from source...

[Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx) on Posh-Git says:

> Once you have Posh-Git loaded up, your PowerShell window lights up with extra...

And the [Posh-Git repository](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installing) installation instructions gives high-level install instructions.

Together, these three links give a high level map of setting up and using Git locally but do not go into details.

So, what we want is a a step-by-step guide to installing Git, installing Posh-Git, and then loading up Posh.

Comment: You are unlikely to get an answer for your question in it's current form. If you could describe any particular problems that you are having while installing them, along with error messages if any, you are much more likely to get useful answers. Questions like "write code for me" or "write guide for me" do not fly well on SO. Questions that are asking to recommend a tool, library or an off-site resource are simply off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit for building Git for Windows. (For what it's worth, I've never built Git on Windows and don't consider myself to have missed out.)

Once you have Git built (or [installed](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20for%20official%20git)):

1. Add the location of `git.exe` to your `%PATH%`
2. Clone posh-git to a directory of your choosing
3. Run posh-git's `install.ps1` to install the default prompt in your `$PROFILE`

Comment: Thank you. Having succeeded I can corroborate that you have not missed out; although, I did learn a smidgen more about both posh and PowerShell profiles.